# Потеря state React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Не пойму, почему теряется стейт при отработке события, если я его, вроде, не мутирую.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот функции, перезаписывающие стейт:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Собственно, возможно еще будет актуален такой вопрос: как вернуться к первоначальному стейту, если я уже отфильтровал и перезаписал его?

Comment: что значит теряется стейт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите вернуть начальное значение, то его нужно где-то хранить, в константе (если список неизменный) или в state (если список меняется от каких-то условий) и от  него отталкиваться при изменении toDoData

```
const initData = [...]
state = {
    toDoData: initData
}
filterAllItems = () => {
    setState({
        toDoData: initData,
    })
}
filterActiveItems = () => {
    setState({
        toDoData: initData.filter(item => !item.done),
    })
}
```